# Unable to launch Minikube Dashboard when virtual switch is set to Internal

Tags: kubernetes, windows-10, hyper-v, minikube

I'm trying to do a POC where I can use kubernetes with virtual switch connection type as Internal only. I managed to start minikube and cluster.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube status
minikube: Running
cluster: Running
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at <**Any random Ip**>
```

but when I run `Minikube Dashboard` command I'm getting following error.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minikube dashboard
Could not find finalized endpoint being pointed to by kubernetes-dashboard: Error validating service: Error getting serv
ice kubernetes-dashboard: Get https://<**Same Ip as above**>:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard:
Service Unavailable
```

**Following are the details**:

```
Driver : HyperV
OS : Windows 10
Dynamic Memory allocation : Disabled
Dynamic MAC allocation : Disabled
NATSwitch connection type : Internal Only
Minikube version : minikube-v0.25.1
Kubectl version : 1.9.0
```

(**With external its work perfectly fine** I need help with **internal** please refer the screenshot)

[[image: Wi-fi property settings[1]]
[image: HyperV virtual switch settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this particular issue and I would like to share with others.

The **root cause** of this issue was proxy settings our network administrator had set some proxy settings policy and that was preventing to access dashboard which was being exposed at `https://<**Same Ip as above**>:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard`

**Solution** for this is you need to check your proxy configuration and update them accordingly.